# log4net with a filter turned off not outputting

Tags: c#, debugging, log4net

I am *sure* I have used this very filter before, but... I have the level up to debug, the filter off (ie, accept on match = true), and a _log.Debug("whatever") in the filter namespace that is not outputting.

I have a logger defined in a class like so, which is part of the namespace used in the filter:

```
    private static readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(IEntityWithTypedId<>));
```

Any ideas on how to figure out why I am not seeing anything and how to fix it?

```
  <log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
        <loggerToMatch value="Smack.Core.Lib.DomainSuperTypes.EntityImpl" />
        <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
      </filter>
      ...
    </appender>
    <root>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

## UPDATE

Well I certainly was doing something silly; I have been in a new project and I hand't as yet added a reference to log4net!

That's the good news though, since it still isn't working properly. It isn't the filter however, since it does work exactly as expected when run from a different project. Adding the watch=true assembly attribute didn't help either.

It's something else stupid  and obvious though (like not having a ref to log4net!) but I don't see it yet.

## Resolved

The output I wasn't seeing was from a logger in a dependent project to the new one I added. The solution has multiple projects which all share the same app.config via symbolic link, which is why I expected things to work in the new project the same as for other projects. But it didn't of course.

That is until I actually added a logger to the new project! Now everything magically works, so I guess that is the reason (can't say that this is really a good log4net feature if so).

Comment: Do you have log4net in the configSections of your app.config (Maybe just post the full config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the filter and then try again.

Comment: Where are you calling this line of code => static readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(IEntityWithTypedId<>)); ?

Comment: Inside of a class of that same name, although you *did* just spot something else. It should not have been the interface, so I took the leading 'I' off. Still no pay dirt though...

Answer (score 2):

Have you defined the XMLConfigurator watcher? This indicates to log4net to read the log4net configuration.

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

Comment: @mrtentju. Your suggestion *did* make me realize I was missing a reference to log4net, see my last update. Not a go from this new project yet though. Cheers